# Ways to improve this code

Tags: scala

I am a Scala newbie, just starting to learn the language.

I solved [Problem 8](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=8) from Project Euler page.

The code looks like this (I removed all the code to do with reading of an input file):

```
def max(n1: Int, n2: Int): Int = Math.max(n1, n2)

def max_product(digits: List[Int], num: Int): Int = {
    def max_core(lst: List[Int], curr_max: Int): Int = lst match {
        case a if lst.length >= num => 
            max_core(a.tail, max(lst.slice(0, num).reduceLeft(_*_), curr_max))
        case _ => curr_max
    }

    max_core(digits, 0)
}

println(max_product(1::2::3::4::2::3::Nil, 2))
```

It works fine, the result is correct. However, I am not completely satisfied with this solution. I don't like the `max_core` sub-function and have the feeling it can be improved. My understanding of FP is, you should iterate over a list, slicing seems to not be the way here.

The question is: how?

Comment: Note: these types of questions are better suited for the Code Review stack exchange site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I would not reinvent the wheel... the method max already is defined in `RichInt`, so you can write `a max b`, for `a` and `b` integers.

<strike>ALso, `slice` is deprecated, therefore</strike> instead of `lst.slice(0, num)` I would use `lst.take(num)`. Deprecated methods will probably be gone when Scala 2.8 is launched.

**EDIT:** Indeed, as [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel) pointed out, `slice(Int, Int)` is not deprecated. I was quite in a hurry when I initially wrote this, and I was thinking of [`slice(Int)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Seq.html#slice%28Int%29), which is equivalent to `drop(Int)`. I still find `lst.take(num)` to be clearer than `lst.slice(0, num)` :).

(nitpick) Your last line does also not compile as you forgot to add `Nil` to the end of your sequence of cons. `1::2::3::4`, would end up invoking `::` on an `Int`, which does not have this method. That's why you need to add `Nil` to the end (invoke `::` on `Nil`).

Also, the algorithm you have used is not obvious at the first glance. The way I would write this is as follows:

```
val numbers = /*"--the string of numbers--"*/.map(_.asDigit).toList

def sliding[A](xs: List[A], w: Int): List[List[A]] = {
  for(n <- List.range(0, xs.size - w)) 
    yield xs drop n take w
}

def product(xs: List[Int]): Int = (1 /: xs) (_ * _)

sliding(numbers, 5).map(product).sort(_ > _).head
```

I feel that the last line explains quite well what the algorithm is supposed to do - take a sliding window of the list, calculate the product in that sliding window and then get the maximum of the calculated products (I have implemented the maximum function as `sort(_ > _).head` out of laziness, I could have done something O(n) rather than O(n log(n)) if performance was critical... it still runs under a second though).

Note that the sliding function will be in the Scala 2.8 library (see [Daniel's  post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319891/calculating-the-moving-average-of-a-list/1320323#1320323), from where I was inspired in writing this definition of sliding).

**EDIT:** Oops... sorry about the `/:`. I just like the conciseness of it and the fact that the initial element of the fold comes before the list. You could equivalently write `product` as the following, to be more explicit:

```
def product(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs.foldLeft(1)(_ * _)
```

`-- Flaviu Cipcigan`

Comment: Thanks Flaviu, that's the answer I hoped for. It took me 5 minutes to understand your solution, mostly because of very concise syntax, that you use. I don't know operators yet, so something like '1 /: xs' is completely cryptic at first glance.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've edited the post to provide the less cryptic definition of the product ;).

Comment: Is `slice` being deprecated? I don't see any warnings on 2.8 or 2.7.4.

Comment: Flaviu, I didn't mean 'cryptic' in a negative way, just cryptic for a complete newbie like me.

Comment: @Daniel: You're right, `slice(Int, Int)` is not deprecated. I was thinking of `slice(Int)` - elaborated in the edited answer.

@Ula: It's a matter of preference which variant you use. That's why I eventually provided both. I am still not sure which one *I* prefer, but I'm inclined towards the `/:` - as it puts the operands in a natural order, though it might be harder to read for people who are not that familiar with syntax or functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I did it.  Nothing fancy.  In your code, you were taking the length of the list in every iteration which is rather wasteful.  I just append the some number of 1s (same as the number of consecutive digits) to the end of the list so I don't need to check the length of the list in order to terminate the loop.

```
val s = ... // string of digits
val ds = s.map(_.asDigit).toList

def findMaxProduct(ds: List[Int], n: Int, max: Int): Int = ds match {
  case Nil => max
  case _ :: rest => findMaxProduct(rest, n, Math.max(max, ds.take(n).reduceLeft(_ * _)))
}

val n = 5 // number of consecutive digits
println(findMaxProduct(ds ::: List.make(n, 1), n, -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

val str = ... // string of digits

val nums = str.map{ _.asDigit }
(0 to nums.size-5).map{ i => nums.slice(i,i+5).product }.max

and another one, more efficient:

(0 to nums.size-5).foldLeft(-1){case(r,i) => r max nums.slice(i,i+5).product}

BTW: works with scala2.8

Answer (score 1):

```
val bigNumber = """73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450""".replaceAll("\\s+","")

def getMax(m: Int, l:List[Seq[Int]]): Int = 
  if (l.head.isEmpty) m else
  getMax(m max l.foldLeft(1) ((acc, l) => acc * l.head), l map (_ tail))

def numDigits(bigNum: String, count: Int) = 
  (1 until count).foldLeft(List(bigNumber map (_ asDigit))) ((l, _) => l.head.tail :: l)

def solve(bigNum: String, count: Int) = getMax(0, numDigits(bigNum, count))

solve(bigNumber, 5)
```

Comment: This solutions requires the number of consecutive digits to be 5. I wanted my code to be more generic.