# Running average in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, moving-average

Is there a pythonic way to **build up a list that contains a running average** of some function?

After reading a fun little piece about [Martians, black boxes, and the Cauchy distribution](http://www.johndcook.com/Cauchy_estimation.html), I thought it would be fun to calculate a running average of the Cauchy distribution myself:

```
import math 
import random

def cauchy(location, scale):
    p = 0.0
    while p == 0.0:
        p = random.random()
    return location + scale*math.tan(math.pi*(p - 0.5))

# is this next block of code a good way to populate running_avg?
sum = 0
count = 0
max = 10
running_avg = []
while count < max:
    num = cauchy(3,1)
    sum += num
    count += 1
    running_avg.append(sum/count)

print running_avg     # or do something else with it, besides printing
```

I think that this approach works, but I'm curious if there might be a more elegant approach to building up that `running_avg` list than using loops and counters (e.g. [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)).

There are some related questions, but they address more complicated problems (small window size, exponential weighting) or aren't specific to Python:

- [calculate exponential moving average in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488670/calculate-exponential-moving-average-in-python)
- [How to efficiently calculate a running standard deviation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174984/how-to-efficiently-calculate-a-running-standard-deviation)
- [Calculating the Moving Average of a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319891/calculating-the-moving-average-of-a-list)

Comment: I'm curious why this is tagged moving-average, since you're actually interested in a running-average (increasing window), not a moving-average (fixed-window)?  If you want to do a moving average there's a nice recipe in http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#deque-recipes :)

Comment: @Jeffrey: you're right -- it was mostly to help people who don't know the right phrase.  But with the useful link you posted, perhaps it would make sense to leave the moving-average tag there?  :)

Comment: @JeffreyHarris, aren't moving average and running average the same thing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could write a generator:

```
def running_average():
  sum = 0
  count = 0
  while True:
    sum += cauchy(3,1)
    count += 1
    yield sum/count
```

Or, given a generator for Cauchy numbers and a utility function for a running sum generator, you can have a neat generator expression:

```
# Cauchy numbers generator
def cauchy_numbers():
  while True:
    yield cauchy(3,1)

# running sum utility function
def running_sum(iterable):
  sum = 0
  for x in iterable:
    sum += x
    yield sum

# Running averages generator expression (** the neat part **)
running_avgs = (sum/(i+1) for (i,sum) in enumerate(running_sum(cauchy_numbers())))

# goes on forever
for avg in running_avgs:
  print avg

# alternatively, take just the first 10
import itertools
for avg in itertools.islice(running_avgs, 10):
  print avg
```

Comment: Awesome.  Just to be clear, would your first example be used like: running_avg = [running_average().next() for i in range(10)]  ?

Comment: Yes, you could use it like that, or you could use `itertools.islice` like in the second example: `for avg in itertools.islice(running_average(), 10):`

Comment: Neat use of generators in this solution, however because of how many you have going on it seems to be ~ 2x slower than a simpler LC solution, although that may just be a trade off for yours being able to handle generators where the LC solution requires a list.

Comment: I timed the simpler LC solution *including generating the Cauchy numbers* (which is what these 2 generator solutions do), and got slower numbers than the generators - see my comment below.

Comment: I did, and you're right about the shift there in timing due to how I removed that portion from the timings, but didn't think that it'd be in yours.  However, check out the new solution I just posted.

Answer (score 6):

You could use coroutines. They are similar to generators, but allows you to send in values. Coroutines was added in Python 2.5, so this won't work in versions before that.

```
def running_average():
    sum = 0.0
    count = 0
    value = yield(float('nan'))
    while True:
        sum += value
        count += 1
        value = yield(sum/count)

ravg = running_average()
next(ravg)   # advance the corutine to the first yield

for i in xrange(10):
    avg = ravg.send(cauchy(3,1))
    print 'Running average: %.6f' % (avg,)
```

As a list comprehension:

```
ravg = running_average()
next(ravg)
ravg_list = [ravg.send(cauchy(3,1)) for i in xrange(10)]
```

**Edits:**

- Using the `next()` function instead of the `it.next()` method. This is so it also will work with Python 3. The `next()` function has also been back-ported to Python 2.6+.
  In Python 2.5, you can either replace the calls with `it.next()`, or define a `next` function yourself.
  (Thanks Adam Parkin)

Comment: Wow, that's quite flexible.  I had no idea that you could use yield to send stuff _into_ a function.

Comment: Note in Python 3 the next syntax is a bit different, do `next(ravg)` rather than `ravg.next()`

Answer (score 4):

I've got two possible solutions here for you.  Both are just generic running average functions that work on any list of numbers. (could be made to work with any iterable)

**Generator based:**

```
nums = [cauchy(3,1) for x in xrange(10)]

def running_avg(numbers):
    for count in xrange(1, len(nums)+1):
        yield sum(numbers[:count])/count

print list(running_avg(nums))
```

**List Comprehension based (really the same code as the earlier):**

```
nums = [cauchy(3,1) for x in xrange(10)]

print [sum(nums[:count])/count for count in xrange(1, len(nums)+1)]
```

**Generator-compatabile Generator based:**

*Edit*: This one I just tested to see if I could make my solution compatible with generators easily and what it's performance would be.  This is what I came up with.

```
def running_avg(numbers):
    sum = 0
    for count, number in enumerate(numbers):
        sum += number
        yield sum/(count+1)
```

See the performance stats below, well worth it.

**Performance characteristics:**

*Edit*: I also decided to test Orip's interesting use of multiple generators to see the impact on performance.

Using timeit and the following (1,000,000 iterations 3 times):

```
print "Generator based:", ', '.join(str(x) for x in Timer('list(running_avg(nums))', 'from __main__ import nums, running_avg').repeat())
print "LC based:", ', '.join(str(x) for x in Timer('[sum(nums[:count])/count for count in xrange(1, len(nums)+1)]', 'from __main__ import nums').repeat())
print "Orip's:", ', '.join(str(x) for x in Timer('list(itertools.islice(running_avgs, 10))', 'from __main__ import itertools, running_avgs').repeat())

print "Generator-compatabile Generator based:", ', '.join(str(x) for x in Timer('list(running_avg(nums))', 'from __main__ import nums, running_avg').repeat())
```

I get the following results:

```
Generator based: 17.653908968, 17.8027219772, 18.0342400074
LC based: 14.3925321102, 14.4613749981, 14.4277560711
Orip's: 30.8035550117, 30.3142540455, 30.5146529675

Generator-compatabile Generator based: 3.55352187157, 3.54164409637, 3.59098005295
```

See comments for code:

```
Orip's genEx based: 4.31488609314, 4.29926609993, 4.30518198013
```

Results are in seconds, and show the <strike>LC</strike> new generator-compatible generator method to be consistently faster, your results may vary though.  I expect the massive difference between my original generator and the new one is the fact that the sum isn't calculated on the fly.

Comment: Interesting.  Any idea (performance-wise) how these approaches compare to orip's first generator example?

Comment: Did you re-generate the Cauchy numbers each time, like the solution above? If not, you're timing the generation of the numbers as well as the running average.

Comment: The timings I get: your LC solution (with generating the numbers each time): [16.687758600203807, 16.715932782820914, 16.738767166880578], my first generator solution: [14.070051607753044, 14.052854863427882, 14.081863001340764], my generator expression: [15.121694400936235, 15.14989374874375, 15.192127309105331]

Comment: No Orip mine doesn't include the time for calculating the numbers each time except on when I tested yours, so that'd play a role into your 2x slower I'm sure.   Although the stats on the new solution I just posted are showing a significant improvement still.

Comment: You're still not generating the numbers. I timed just the numbers generation on my machine (no running sum), and it's clearly what's taking the most time: [9.3933679211354502, 9.4039924096689447, 9.3787265585455089]

Comment: For the summing, your solution with `enumerate` instead of `count+=1` should be faster than the simple generator I showed

Comment: No I'm not, as that's either going to be constant, or noise for the purpose of a running average.

Comment: In order to get a good comparison with the generator-expression solution, run `list((sum/(i+1) for (i,sum) in enumerate(running_sum(nums))))` (nums instead of cauchy_numbers())

Comment: Orip's genEx based: 4.31488609314, 4.29926609993, 4.30518198013