# How to calculate a running average for an infinite iterations?

Tags: python, average, moving-average

I want to calculate the running average over an infinite (or a huge) number of iterations:

```
import random
epochs = 1e10
for epoch in range(epochs):
    new_value = random.randint(1, 100)
    new_running_average = get_avg(previous_average, new_value) # what is this function going to be?
```

The naive approach would be to add any new value `new_value` to a list, and then average the list at each iteration. But, this is not realistic as 1) the number of iterations is far too large, and 2) I have to create many of such averages for many parameters.

The existing SO questions I found around calculating running average (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790550/running-average-in-python) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352047/finding-moving-average-from-data-points-in-python)) use a fix data list that is relatively small, so it's rather trivial.

Comment: What if you only needed a running *sum*; how would you solve that?  If you have the sum and the count, getting the average is trivial.

Comment: @ScottHunter That is a good point, since the running average would be the running sum divided by the current count -- correct? The issue is then saving a variable that contains the running sum which might get quite large. I'm wondering if there's a potentially more space-efficient way, but this might work as a potential solution

Comment: How much "space" do you think the sum will take up?

Comment: You don't need to store (in a list or whatever) all the random numbers. You just need to sum them and keep a count of the number of times you add to an accumulator. Divide the running total (the accumulator) by the current count and you have your moving average

Comment: "The existing SO questions I found around calculating running average (e.g., this or this) use a fix data list that is relatively small, so it's rather trivial." The top and accepted answer for the first of those links clearly shows a technique that handles an arbitrary amount of input data, by `yield`ing each value as it's computed. It works equally well with a lazy iterator input, too.

Comment: Aside from that: if the question is really "given the current running average, the next value and the number of elements seen so far, how do I compute an average that incorporates the next value?", than that is *purely a math question, not a programming question*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the amount of numbers already in the average:

```
def get_avg(nums_in_average, previous_average, new_value):
    return ((nums_in_average*previous_average)+new_value)/(nums_in_average + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your source is an iterator (or iterable), you can create a generator function that will go through it and spit out the current average as it goes.  No need for a table:

```
def runAvg(source):
    average = 0
    for count,value in enumerate(source,1):
        average = (average*(count-1) + value) / count
        yield value, average
```

Usage:

```
import random

epochs = int(1e10)
source = (random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(epochs))
for value,average in runAvg(source):
    print(value,average)

72 72.0
96 84.0
94 87.33333333333333
38 75.0
36 67.2
86 70.33333333333333
47 67.0
91 70.0
80 71.11111111111111
16 65.6
23 61.72727272727273
25 58.666666666666664
40 57.23076923076923
...
```

If you don't want to write your own generator, you can use accumulate and tee from itertools:

```
import random

epochs = int(1e10)
source = (random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(epochs))

from itertools import accumulate, tee

source,cum = tee(source)
for count,total in enumerate(accumulate(cum),1):
    print(next(source),total/count)

40 40.0
10 25.0
35 28.333333333333332
66 37.75
49 40.0
19 36.5
86 43.57142857142857
69 46.75
19 43.666666666666664
95 48.8
43 48.27272727272727
```