# Clojure equivalent of this Haskell Moving Average Function?

Tags: haskell, clojure

Attempting to understand the differences between Clojure and Haskell. I have the following code which calculates the moving average of a time-series list of numbers:

```
movavg n []     = []
movavg n (x:xs) = map (/ n') sums
    where
        sums = scanl (+) (n' * x) $ zipWith (-) xs (replicate n x ++ xs)
        n'   = fromIntegral n
```

What would be the idiomatic version of this in Clojure?

Comment: is this one equivalent? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1320425/24946

Comment: No, not in terms of efficiency. The difference is in the way that redundant computations are eliminated.

Comment: I can't get the haskell code to work, can you provide a simple example where you are invoking movavg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why a very literal translation of this shouldn't be idiomatic, i.e.:

```
(defn movavg [n coll]
  (when-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)]
    (map #(/ % n)
         (reductions + (* n x)
                     (map - xs (concat (repeat n x) xs))))))
```

Particularly code with a lot of sequence functions has always the potential to be very close to Haskell since they're lazy.

**Edit**: Shortened code according to Justin Kramer's suggestion.

Comment: `(if (empty? coll) nil (let [[x & xs] coll] ...))` can be shortened to `(when-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)] ...)`

Comment: @JustinKramer: Thanks, changed my answer accordingly.